# scl enable rh-mariadb102 bash doesn't work with Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, mariadb, software-collections

I'm new to stackoverflow... It seems to be a pretty good place to share knowledge and to find solution with a very interesting community.

I've a problem with Ansble and the "scl" "mysql_install_dir" commands.

When I execute manually "scl enable rh-mariadb102 bash && mysql_install_dir ..." it's perfectly working when I do it right in the server's console.

But when I try to build a task on Ansible :

```
- name: "Execute mysql_install_db to prepare DB"
  shell: |
    scl enable rh-mariadb102 bash
    mysql_install_db --datadir=/data/{{ item.instance_name }}/db/mariadb102
  become_user: root
  with_items: "{{ vars_list }}"
```

It return error :

"Use \"scl enable rh-mariadb102 'service ...'\" invocation"

This seems like Ansible doesn't execute well the scl enable command... or something like this.

Someone have been stuck before with this issue ?

Thanks for the help and sorry for bad english.

Comment: Explain [your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) what you are doing in each step.

Answer (score 7):

The `scl` command opens a subshell and cloes it again.  Something like this should work:

```
- name: "Execute mysql_install_db to prepare DB"
  shell: |
    scl enable rh-mariadb102 -- mysql_install_db --datadir=/data/{{ item.instance_name }}/db/mariadb102
  become_user: root
  with_items: "{{ vars_list }}"
```

That is, run the actual command under `scl enable`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this solved my issue ! I was trying to execute the command scl and mysql_install_db with && ... or any other way = don't work. 

I wasn't perfectly aware of subshell mecanism of scl. 

Now my multi-instance rh-mariadb102 playbook is working.